# Swift can't change text size of button inside stackview

Tags: swift, xcode, button

this might be a silly question, but I'm still in learning phase of coding and swift.
The problem is in the question and here is how I'm doing it right now:

[picture of cell and button attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWA8m.png)

The problem is that the size I change in there doesn't apply when I run the app, when app is running that size is set to a standard like 17 or 18.

Comment: After many hours I tried a new cell in my other project and it worked perfectly fine. So I guess it's just a bug or something

Comment: The size of the cell is defined by tableView. This may lead to contraints on cell contents being resized